# Add attribute to instance in entity

Tags: java, spring

I have an spring data   entity:

```
public class Product{
    private Store minStore;
    private Store maxStore;
    private List<Store> stores;
}
```

My store class is consist by one field - store name. But i need to add in minStore & maxStore additional fields  - double minPrice(MinStore),double maxPrice(MaxStore). I don't need to add this field to the store class , so how  i can add this attribute to the instance ? In my spring service i can do something like this -

```
maxStore = new Store(storeName,offers){
            double maxPrice = salePrice ;
            public void setMaxPrice(double maxPrice){
                this.maxPrice = maxPrice;
            }
            public double getMaxPrice(){
                return this.maxPrice;
            }
        };
```

But this fields will be not available outside my service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce new class `StorePrice`:

```
class StorePrice {
    Store store;
    double maxPrice;
    double minPrice;
}
```

and then use it instead of `Store`

```
public class Product{
    private Store minStore;
    private Store maxStore;
    private List<StorePrice> stores;
}
```

Comment: I think it fits. tnks:)

Answer (score 0):

**You can't.**

It is impossible to change class in runtime (after compilation).